# Set bitmap invisible while clicked with creatjs

Tags: javascript, createjs

There is a simple requirement:
I have a bitmap in the background(invisible), and on the top there is another bitmap(visible),while I click the top bitmap.the background will show,and the top will invisible.
her is my code

```
        var bitmap =  new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("blue").drawRect(0,0,60,60));;
        bitmap.x = x;
        bitmap.y = y;
        bitmap.name = r + "," + c;
        bitmap.on("click", function (evt) {
            alert("click " + evt.target.name)
            evt.target.isVisible = false;
        });
        this.addChild(bitmap);
```

the problem is :when I click the top,I got an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function
```

How can I fix it? 
or any other way to resolve this requirement? 
a sample is better ,Thanks a lot.

Comment: resolved:      evt.target.visible = false;    not isvisible

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var bitmapRect = new createjs.Graphics();
bitmapRect.beginFill("blue").drawRect(0,0,60,60);
var bitmap = new createjs.Shape(bitmapRect);
...
```

Comment: Both this approach, and the one in the original question show correct methods for attaching graphics to a Shape. This answer does not address the question. I am not sure why it is marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @Lanny I have not used createjs but I assume `new createjs.Graphics()` returns a createjs.Graphics() object whereas `new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("blue").drawRect(0,0,60,60)` returns a boolean. If you use `new createjs.Shape(new createjs.Graphics().beginFill("blue").drawRect(0,0,60,60))` you may as well be doing new `createjs.Shape(false)`. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are incorrect. All of the drawing commands return a reference to the Graphics object, so that they can be chained: `new Graphics().beginFill("red").drawCircle(0,0,50).etc();`

Comment: Right! Would you advise I remove my answer?

Comment: Hi,Lanny,thank you support. http://community.createjs.com/discussions/createjs/2335-set-bitmap-invisible-while-clicked-with-creatjs